# Merge sort doesn't work reursively

Tags: java, list, sorting, recursion, merge

I want to build an algorithm where I'm sorting a linked list via merge sort. Here the code:

```
private Item mergeSort(Item l){
    //if the list contains of just one item we don't have to sort it anymore
    if(l.next == null) return l;
    //divide your list in two parts and get both starts of both lists
    Item middle = getMidItem(l);
    Item start1 = l;
    Item start2 = middle.next;
    middle.next = null;
    //process recursively the same process but with the both new lists until both lists only contain of one item
    Item item1 = mergeSort(start1);
    Item item2 = mergeSort(start2);
    //if both lists are sorted put them together
    return merge(item1, item2);
}
```

This function works recursively. First, if it hasn't another element, I return the current one and stop the function. If it has more than one element, I determine the middle of the element (getMidItem works properly I've debugged it several times) and divide both lists in two parts. After that, I recursively open the function again and do it for both lists now until the list contains of just one element. If this going to happen, I return all elements and merge them.

The merge function determines which element is the smaller one, puts the references of the smaller one on the front and the bigger one on the end, until it has run over the whole list. The problem in here is, my whole structure. If I run it he will get to one point, where the lists contains of just one element and he returns it, saves it and merges only in the last recursion step and stops it. And in the end, I don't get my list, but only the first element of the list.

I realized that this isn't going to work, but I have actually no clue, how I can rewrite it, so that it does what I want. I know how merge sort does work, but I don't know how to implement it, like this way. And before somebody says, that "it is hard that way, just rewrite the method body and return the first, the middle and the last one or do it with an array", I have to do it that way. It's homework.

Here is the `merge` function:

```
public static Item merge(Item a, Item b){
    //if both items are null return null, if one is null return the other
    if(a == null && b == null) return null;
    else if(a == null && b != null) return b;
    else if(a != null && b == null) return a;
    else{
        //create minimum and check if 'a' or 'b' is smaller and set it to minimum
        Item min = null;
        //if a is smaller than b, a should be returned and the next item of 'a' should be 'b'
        if(a.value.compareTo(b.value) < 0){
            //the next reference of the smaller element should be the bigger one
            min = a;
            a = a.next;
        }
        else{
            //same but the other way around
            min = b;
            b = b.next;

        }
        //you create the next reference of the minimum 
        Item p = min;
        if(a != null && b != null){
            //you iterate through the whole list and put the references of the smaller one on the front and the bigger one behind
            while(a.next != null && b.next != null){
                if(a.value.compareTo(b.value) < 0){
                    p.next = a;
                    a = a.next;
                }
                else{
                    p.next = b;
                    b = b.next;
                }
            }
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the source of `merge()`

Comment: I agree with @JimGarrison: the problem is most likely within `merge(...)` (the rest of your sorting looks fine so far). From what you described, I suspect you have some problem in merging the two lists into one new list. One way to test this would be to asser that the newly merged list has the length of `start1 + start2` (before merging, of course).

Comment: Are you working in an IDE with a debugger (Eclipse, Idea, NetBeans)?  If yes, set up a simple test case with five elements and step through the code, examining the variables as you go.  If you are not using an IDE, stop, download one, and learn to use the debugger.  That is a requirement of writing and debugging software.

Comment: I use one in Elipse. If you read my question a bit preciser you can spot ' (getMidItem works properly I've debugged it several times)'. If I hadn't debugged it, I couldn't evel tell you, where I assume my mistake.

Comment: If interested, there's a faster iterative method for sorting a linked list, using the same mergelist function, but instead of recursion, it uses an array of pointers to nodes to point to lists of size 1, 2, 4, 8, ... and merges nodes into the array, then merges the array to form a single sorted list, a type of bottom up merge sort for linked list. I can post example code later if anyone asks to see this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical problem with your `merge(...)`method when merging the lists:

```
   if(a != null && b != null){ // PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
        //you iterate through the whole list and put the references of the smaller one on the front and the bigger one behind
        while(a.next != null && b.next != null){ // AND HERE
            if(a.value.compareTo(b.value) < 0){
                p.next = a;
                a = a.next;
            }
            else{
                p.next = b;
                b = b.next;
            }
        }
    }
```

You check whether `a != null && b != null`. What if only one list is `null`? In this case you neglect content from the second list and therefore loose data. You have to account for the fact that one of the lists may run out of data (i.e. is `null`) while the other list still holds elements.

Make a pen & paper-test with your mergesort and an already sorted list. This should reveal the problem.